# string.replace() doesnt seem to work

Tags: python

So I have a `function` `guess_check(guess)` that is invoked by `prompt()` `function`

`Prompt()` invokes `guess_check()` so that guess is a one work `string` containing an alphabet character.

word is a variable = `"placeholder"`

Below is the code that I'm having trouble with:

```
if guess in word:
    word.replace(guess, '*')
print word
```

If I make guess = "a" I would anticipate word = "pl*ceholder", but it doesn't change.

Why does the word variable not change, and how can I get it to change as I want?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: we need to have a primary source for all these duplicates [How best to redirect all duplicates of “Why didn't <Python string method> do anything/assign a result”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287093/how-best-to-redirect-all-duplicates-of-why-didnt-python-string-method-do-any)

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable, so you need to reassign the result of the method call:

```
if guess in word:
    word = word.replace(guess, '*')
print word
```

As a rule of thumb, methods on immutable objects (strings, tuples etc.) usually return a new value whereas methods on mutable objects (lists, dicts, sets etc.) modify the object in-place, which is why you can do

```
>>> l = [3, 2, 4, 1]
>>> l.sort()
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

but not (which is another typical beginner's mistake)

```
>>> l = l.sort()
```

because `list.sort()` doesn't return anything (which means it returns `None`), so that line would assign `None` to `l`:

```
>>> print l
None
```